# Populating the ImageData.plist in PhotoScroller example

Tags: iphone, ios, plist, nsdictionary, writetofile

I am still fairly new to iPhone app development and I need your help. I am trying to populate the imageData.plist in Apple's [PhotoScroller example](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/PhotoScroller/Introduction/Intro.html)  with images of my own, can you please guide me on how to populate this plist file programmatically, based on all the images in the full images folder? The other challenge I have is that any number of unknown images could be placed inside the folder at any time. Below is a snapshot of the plist file.

Definition of plist table

```
Item 0   Dictionary  (3 items)

height   Number      400

width    Number      290

name     string      Lake


Item 1   Dictionary  (3 items)

height   Number      400

width    Number      290

name     string      Tree


Item 2   Dictionary  (3 items)

height   Number      400

width    Number      290

name     string      Shed


Item 3   Dictionary  (3 items)

height   Number      400

width    Number      290

name     string      Rock
```

I know that I have to use NSDictionary class and writeToFile to achieve this, but how to go about this I need help.

Answer (score 0):

An array of NSDictionarys?

```
NSMutableArray *dicts = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:10];
NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[NSNumber numberWithInt:400], @"height", [NSNumber numberWithInt:290], @"width", @"Lake", @"name", nil];
[dicts addObject:dict];
//and so on...

NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *filePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"filename.plist"];

[dicts writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
```